# Channel Factory not registered when trying to store a SharedString within root SharedDirectory

Tags: fluid-framework

I tried to create and store a new `SharedString` DDS on my root `SharedDirectory` with following code:

```ts
protected async initializingFirstTime() {
    const text = SharedString.create(this.runtime);
    this.root.set("text", text.handle)
}
```

When I run the app, I get following error in JavaScript console:

```ts
app.ts:49 Error: Channel Factory https://graph.microsoft.com/types/mergeTree not registered
at new LocalChannelContext (localChannelContext.js:19)
at FluidDataStoreRuntime.createChannel (dataStoreRuntime.js:169)
at Function.create (sharedString.js:33)
at DiceRoller.<anonymous> (dataObject.ts:43)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at dataObject.ts:4
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at ./src/dataObject.ts.__awaiter (dataObject.ts:4)
at DiceRoller.initializingFirstTime (dataObject.ts:42)
at DiceRoller.initializeInternal (pureDataObject.js:87)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure you are registering all DDS types with your Data Object Factory.

```js
public static readonly factory = new DataObjectFactory(
        SomeFluidObject.Name,
        SomeFluidObject,
        [
            SharedString.getFactory(),
        ],
        {},
    );
```